# Are there any other planets besides Arda in Ea?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-silmarillion, arda

Did Tolkien mention anything about other planets in his mythology or did he invent just the one planet for his stories?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmology_of_Tolkien%27s_legendarium#The_physical_universe - Basically loads.

Comment: Hmm, what you mean by planet seems important here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No other planets are visited in the Legendarium<sup>1</sup>, but several of Tolkien's dictionaries (published in *History of Middle-earth* in a number of places) include Quenya and Sindarin names for what we now know of as planets<sup>2</sup>; whether they were known to be planets by the inhabitants of Middle-earth is unknown.

Some examples:

- **Morwen** (Gnommish) and **Silindo** (Quenya): Jupiter (from *The Book of Lost Tales, Part 1*)
- **Carnil** (Mars)
- **Luini** (possibly Neptune)
- **Nénar** (possibly also Neptune)
- **Lumbar** (Saturn)
- **Alcarinquë** (Jupiter)
- **Elemmírë** (possibly Mercury)

The final examples are from the Index of *Morgoth's Ring*.

As TGnat reminds me in comments, the star known as Eärendil corresponds to what we would call the planet Venus. The complication here is that we *know* what Eärendil is: it's a half-elf (named Eärendil, funnily enough) flying through the air with a Silmaril strapped to his forehead, so it's definitely *not* a planet.

Since no further details about the other "planets" I've named above are given, it's entirely possible that they are *also* not actually planets in Tolkien's cosmology, but some other kind of thing. Unfortunately we don't know for sure.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except Aman, which is *sort of* another planet after the Fall of Númenor

<sup>2</sup> This pre-supposes that Middle-earth is in our solar system, which was Tolkien's intention. We have a number of questions about that on this site, including [How exactly is Arda supposed to be an ancient Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26808/how-exactly-is-arda-supposed-to-be-an-ancient-earth) and [Is Tolkien's Middle-earth in our Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22034/is-tolkiens-middle-earth-in-our-universe) and [In what time period does The Lord of the Rings take place in the real world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/in-what-time-period-does-the-lord-of-the-rings-take-place-in-the-real-world)

Comment: Earendil = Venus?

Comment: @TGnat Yes, but Earendil isn't a planet in Tolkien's fictional universe; it's a Silmaril

Comment: Eärendil is a *satellite*, so it depends on your definition of planet. [glares at Neil DeGrasse Tyson angrily]

Comment: @Ber is it spherical?

Comment: The Lengendarium are technically supposed to be in-Universe legends - some based on truth, others completely metaphorical. So Eärendil can be an actual planet Venus and the Half-Elf, just as for us it's an actual planet and a love goddess.

Answer (score 1):

From the Silmarillion, when Varda creates the Stars:

> Then Varda went forth from the council, and she looked out from the height of Taniquetil, and beheld the darkness of Middle-earth beneath the innumerable stars, faint and far. Then she began a great labour, greatest of all the works of the Valar since their coming into Arda. She took the silver dews from the vats of Telperion, and therewith she made new stars and brighter against the coming of the Firstborn; wherefore she whose name out of the deeps of time and the labours of Eä was Tintallë, the Kindler, was called after by the Elves Elentári, Queen of the Stars. **Carnil and Luinil, Nénar and Lumbar, Alcarinquë and Elemmírë she wrought in that time**, and many other of the ancient stars she gathered together and set as signs in the heavens of Arda: Wilwarin, Telumendil, Soronúmë, and Anarríma; and Menelmacar with his shining belt, that forebodes the Last Battle that shall be at the end of days. And high in the north as a challenge to Melkor she set the crown of seven mighty stars to swing, Valacirca, the Sickle of the Valar and sign of doom.
> <sub>*The Silmarillion* - Chapter 3 - "Of the Coming of the Elves and the Captivity of Melkor"</sub>

In particular note the phrase "Carnil and Luinil, Nénar and Lumbar, Alcarinquë and Elemmírë she wrought in that time".

A c.1951 manuscript of this passage which is kept in the Marquette collection (MS 3/9/36), has the following letters above each name:

> Carnil = **M**
> Lumbar = **S**
> Luinil = (no letter)
> Nénar = **<s>N</s>** (crossed out)
> Alcarinquë = **Jup**
> Elemmírë = **M**
> <sub>*Vinyar Tengwar* #12, "Nole i Meneldilo: Lore of the Astronomer"</sub>

In *Vinyar Tengwar* #12, editors Jorge Quinonez and Ned Raggett reason that this is likely a list of planet names, and so the "S" would be Saturn, and the two "M's" Mars and Mercury, distinguished by fact that one of them includes the root *carn-* 'red'. Excluding Pluto (which may have been too small for the elves to see), Earth (which is Arda), and Venus (which is Eärendil), that leaves Neptune and Uranus for the two remaining ones. They point out that *luin-* means blue and so associate Luinil with Neptune, and thus arriving at the following list:

- Elemmírë = Mercury
- Carnil = Mars
- Alcarinquë = Jupiter
- Lumbar = Saturn
- Nénar = Uranus
- Luinil = Neptune

In the introduction to the index of *Morgoth's Ring*, Christopher Tolkien discusses this manuscript page and the conclusion reached in Vinyar Tengwar, saying that "this conclusion appears to be no mere ingenious deduction but to derive from my father's own clear indications". Christopher admits that he finds it strange that Uranus and Neptune should appear on a list of bright celestial objects, but supposes that his father must have previously independently decided on names for all the planets prior to drafting that passage.

Comment: I wouldn't put it past the Eldar to invent the telescope.

Comment: @Spencer - They also gave as another reason why Pluto might be excluded because it was only discovered in 1933, which may have been too late for Tolkien to incorporate it. I don't know if that is true, but if Christopher's theory about this being an older list Tolkien was pulling out is true, then that could make sense.

Comment: I'm reminded of a science fiction story where some guy becomes convinced that the universe sort of reboots itself when a new observer dependent discovery is made and that in fact the previous theory was truely correct at the time.   That is the Earth WAS flat until someone broke the universe with a new theory.  Newton was correct until Einstein broke it with relativity.   Given in the Earth changed from flat to a globe in the Silmarillion universe - the planets could be expected to also be radically revised in their nature to match a less mythological form of physics - like that story.